# Paypal_IPN doesn't get the result?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I watched a tutorial and did exactly what the guy did. I have the following code for my `index.php`. The guy in the tutorial recieves a result ( from $result variable ) but i get nothing.

var_dump on $result:

`string(0) ""`

Where is the problem?

```
<?php

class Paypal_IPN 
{

    public function __construct($mode)
    {
        if ($mode == 'live') 
            $this->_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
        else
            $this->_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    }

    public function run()
    {

        $postFields = "cdm=_notify-validate";

        foreach ((array)$_POST as $key => $value) 
        {
            $postFields .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);  
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL             => $this->_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_POST            => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $postFields
        ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $fh = fopen('result.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $result . " -- \n" . $postFields);
        fclose($fh);

        var_dump( $result );
    }

}

$paypal = new Paypal_IPN('sandbox');
$paypal->run();
```

I should have recieved INVALID or VALID as result...

Comment: You may want to add some error handling to your curl execution. Possibly throwing an error you don't know about. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the string

```
$postFields = "cdm=_notify-validate";
```

Should be

```
$postFields = "cmd=_notify-validate";
```